# Jenkins terminology: builds are deployed to servers. Are plugins needed to get Jenkins to work?

Tags: plugins, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

In Jenkins, what are the destination servers of the builds called?  For Chef, they are Chef clients.  For Puppet, they are agents.  For Jenkins' farms, the slave servers are called nodes.  Is there a specific term that Jenkins uses for the build destination servers?

Where do you configure these servers to deploy to?  I'm not asking about slave nodes but servers that receive the continuous integration.  I know how to set up Jenkins.  I just don't know how to configure which servers on the network should receive builds.  Can you use Jenkins to automate builds without plugins?  Or are "Publish Over" plugins necessary?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no term like "build destination server" in Jenkins. the Jenkins master hosts your projects. A project run is a build. The product of a build is called artifact. Builds are using the project workspace for the build run. Normally this is the location where your artifacts are located when your build finished.

In Jenkins there are many ways to deal with this artifacts. A simple and I think the most common way is to use the post build action **Archive the artifacts**. This will copy the artifacts from the project workspace into the build archive of your project.

There are many ways and plugins to deal with artifacts:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders